# How to combine cells of jTable in one?

Tags: java, jtable

I am developing an application containing a table. I've imported a database in this table but SQL generated a repetition of some  names  like showing in the picture below.

So I want to combine those cells in one and erase the repetition but I don't know how so I am asking for your help.

```
ResultSet rs = selection("SELECT `Nom produit`, `CIE/SFIN`, `obj Fpy`, `poste`" + semaine + " FROM `allin`" + "where `Nom produit`='" + rsnomprod.getString(1) + "' ORDER BY `allin`.`SFIN OU CIE` ASC");
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>(columns);

//  Get column names
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
}

columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
int ligne = 0;
String val;

while (rs.next()) {
    row = new Vector(columnCount);
    ligne++;

    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        val = rs.getString(i);
        row.add(val);
    }

    data.add(row);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Aggregation should be done on the data (on your List from SQL) not at the JTable, the JTable only represents the data you have.

Comment: I don't recall that JTable supports row spanning.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are saying am sorry